# assembly take in input number without echo(emu8086)

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm using emu8086 to code

So

```
str01 db "Enter a number $"

Number db ?

Lea dx,str01
Mov ah,9
Int 21h

Mov ah,1
Int 21h
```

So how can i take that number without showing it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but according to [Ralph Brown's interrupt list of INT 21h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm) your code

```
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
```

calls the
*INT 21h/AH=01h function*
[READ CHARACTER FROM STANDARD INPUT, WITH ECHO](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm).

So, to avoid console output, you probably should call the
*INT21h/AH=07h function*
[DIRECT CHARACTER INPUT, WITHOUT ECHO](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2560.htm).

So your code should probably look like this:

```
mov ah, 07
int 21h
```